# codeigniter session losing session state when hosted with phpfog

Tags: session, hosting, session-state, php

I've built a php/codeigniter app which worked perfectly when I hosted it with rackspace on a vps. I've recently migrated it over to phpfog's hosting environment however I'm running into an issue with my user's sessions.

I'm using the sessions class to store data in the database. The problem I'm seeing is that on the initial page request, two session records are created in the database. And then for every page request following that a new session record is created. The application loses its session when going from page to page.

I'm not sure what could be causing this, maybe the cache-layer or the load balancer of phpfog? Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

After playing around with this for quite some time I might have been able to track this bug down to a @font-face include in one of my CSS files????????

```
/*
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ColaborateLightRegular';
    src: url('/application/assets/web/css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/application/assets/web/css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('/application/assets/web/css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/application/assets/web/css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/application/assets/web/css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.svg#webfontR2xcGGVv') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
*/
```

When that block of code is not commented out in a style sheet included on many of my website's pages, a new session is created in my database. When it is commented out, the new session doesn't occur? I'll look into it a bit more tomorrow because right now I'm falling asleep but this is pretty weird. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you read/write cookies? Does the session persist without DB storage?

Comment: As far as reading/writing cookies goes, I can tell that my server is sending the header: "Set-Cookie ci_csrf_token=2c673e4052dbad447ed82340c4c0878d; expires=Tue, 19-Jul-2011 00:46:03 GMT; path=/" and that any calls to $this->session->userdata('field_i_previously_set') fail since the server seems to initiate a session every time it starts

Comment: I'll give it a shot without db storage I was just really hoping to avoid going that route

Comment: I'm not saying to drop DB sessions, just looking for more info for your answerers so you can get help.

Comment: Yeah I understand, yes the session is still lost after I disable using the db. I might have described it inaccurately, my session persists for seemingly 1 request, then is lost. So my log in screen authenticates, loads my site's home page, and then if I refresh the home page the session has been lost and it shows the login screen again. And I also see a new db record in my sessions table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I eventually determined what was causing the extra sessions to appear in my database. I had modified codeigniter to render a custom 404 page with a controller and a view, and this page was causing a new session to be generated. Essentially my browser would be looking for an image that didn't exist on my server, and since the browser was requesting an image/static resource it wasn't passing along a cookie for it. The 404-controller would then get initiated and since no cookie was passed it would assume this was a new session and generate one. Pretty tricky bug to track down.

Comment: Thank you! I was going insane trying to fix pyrocms.com. For some reason the blog was causing people to log in. Blog somehow included store.css, and store.css was looking for a non-existant image. My greedy 404 rewriting was making the actual 404 page load, which created a new PHP session! This caused a few WTF's but was easy to fix in the end! :D

Comment: @Phil Sturgeon, I'm glad I could help you. :)

Comment: Yeah Thanks @CaseyFlynn.  I got bitten by this one too.